# Logical Proofs involving powersets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I have no idea how to work on the following proof. Any Suggestions?

Prove that for any sets A and B, if P(A) ∪ P(B) = P(A ∪ B) then either A ⊆ B or B ⊆ A.

Thanks

Comment: The union symbol makes no sense between two numbers (the two probabilities P(A) and P(B).) Also even if it were replaced with + the statement wouldn't hold.

Comment: It's the power set: the set of all subsets.  $\mathcal P(A) = \{X: X\subseteq A\}$

Comment: Bad comment -- look at the title of the question.  $P(S)$ is in this context being used as the power set of set $S$ (the set of all subsets of $S$).

Comment: @MarkFischler Agreed, read too fast!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose there exists $ a \in A, a \notin B  $ and $ b \notin A, b \in B $ (contradictory to the hypothesis).

Then $ \{a,b\} \in P(A\cup B) $, but $ \{a,b\} \notin P(A) \cup P(B) $ and it's a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

We have $A \cup B \in P(A \cup B) = P(A) \cup P(B)$. Therefore $A \cup B \in P(A)$ or $A \cup B \in P(B)$.

Say, for instance, that it's the first. Then $B \subseteq A \cup B \subseteq A$.

In the second case, we likewise prove $A \subseteq B$.